# The menu with options for Sapling Tree Gen creation is no longer available

Tags: sapling-addon

I using Blender 2.78 and this add-on:
Add Curve: Sapling Tree Gen

Problem: add-on menu is disappeared.

I created tree and clicked Undo button to cancel action , but the menu dissapered. Turned into new menu Operator.

Before
[image: Before]
After (dissapered menu is marked red. This is my problem.)
[image: After]

Any problem solution? I'm very sad.

Comment: This is normal behaviour for operators in blender.

Comment: Either edit those options until satisfied with the result or add another tree and edit its options. You can export preset while menu is accessible to save options for later use

Comment: Problem solution is Python console , Settings or blender files. But how to edit Settings or Python or Files?

Comment: So how to edit this?

Comment: What do you want to edit? How is Python console and blender files are related to this? As is stated in the linked answer you can't edit the object (any object in Blender except for rare cases) after it was created *and* another operation was done (e.g. you moved the tree created with Sapling addon). This is thoroughly explained in the linked answer. If you have any other question (not this one) please ask it as a new question.